# What Constitutes a Rant?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This meta question is based on ["Why are the candidates allowed to speak after their two minutes runs out?"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/12417/why-are-the-candidates-allowed-to-speak-after-their-two-minutes-runs-out)

The text of the question is:

> In most major American debates, the candidates get a fixed amount of time to make their points. In theory, when the clock runs out they're finished. In practice, Donald Trump talks over everybody. Why don't they just shut off the microphone when it's not someone's turn to speak?

This question attracted some down votes (and close votes). At least one reason that was apparent in the comments was that the question was viewed as being a rant.

Is this a kind of question that should be accepted on politics.SE? What about this question makes it a good or bad fit?

Answer (score 6):

When we say a "rant" what we're talking about is a "Question" that is not actually a question.

If your question is

> Obama Sucks.  Am I right?

It has the syntactical form of a question, but in spirit it is not actually a question.  It does not actually seek an answer, rather, its purpose is to tell us something.

---

Generally, so long as your question contains a real question, then it should not be closed for "being a rant".  If it contains a rant, the correct course of action would be to edit that rant out.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but the real issue is the question reads like "I think (**my opinion**) the microphone should be turn off". What is **your opinion**? Some will say, "Yeah, I agree. Why not?" Some will say, "No, why? Let them speak a little longer. Is it that bad? I don't think so". The real question here is "is this a real question that can be answered differently?"

Answer (score -2):

Adding to other answers, this question should be directed to [**Commission on Presidential Debates**](http://www.debates.org/) which sets all the rules about presidential debates.

In addition, as I commented to the question, allowing a little longer time for each candidate (or speaking briefly while other candidates are speaking) is just a common sense in any debate unless it is strictly prohibited by the rules or the rules say the microphone should be turned off after X amount of time given to each candidate.

As I commented to @SamIam's answer,

> The real issue is the question reads like "I think (**my opinion**) the
> microphone should be turned off". What is **your opinion**? Some will say,
> "Yeah, I agree. Why not?" Some will say, "No, why? Let them speak a
> little longer. Is it that bad? I don't think so".
>
> The real question
> here is "is this a real question that can be answered differently?"